# ASP.NET : Globalization error

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, silverlight, globalization

I've a problem with serialization both in silverlight and asp.net.

I've added this line to my web.config to set the culture of my web application:

```
<globalization uiCulture="fr-CA" culture="fr-CA"/>
```

Problem: when my computer is set to another culture for example en-UK, my application is taking that culture instead of the one i set in the web.config.

Comment: en-UK is invalid en-GB is correct.  Not related to the problem though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your site might be honoring the browser's stated language preference.

Check the Language settings in the browser, and try setting `enableClientBasedCulture` in your `web.config` to `false`, per this [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz9tc508.aspx).

Also worth making sure you try other basic troubleshooting steps, like resetting IIS (assuming you're not using the built-in Visual Studio development web server).

If those steps fail, I would roll up my sleeves and try some serious debugging. It's possible something else is overriding your setting, or that ASP.NET isn't finding your `.resx` resource file.

Try overriding the `InitializeCulture` method on a page and hardcoding the language there (assuming you're using Webforms). That will also let you set a breakpoint while the page is loading and check what the `UICulture` is set to.

If the cultures are getting set properly, I'd look to make sure everything is set up correctly with your `.resx`. Those things can be a pain to get configured in my experience.

It might be a good idea to set up a simple HelloWorld demo app to try to reproduce and isolate the problem. Here's a decent [walk-through](http://net.blogs.webucator.com/2010/04/07/creating-multi-language-hello-world-kiosk-page/) so you can check your setup steps.

Comment: I've used InitializeCulture and it works thanks :) I've tested UICulture and it wasn't set to the culture I need. It seems that the settings in the web.config only set the default language not the language to use, so the the app takes the system culture.